# Is $2$-avoidability determinable?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Is it decidable if a given word is $2$-avoidable? That is, does there exist an algorithm which can determine for a given pattern whether every infinite binary word contains that pattern?

It seems that the more general question whether it is possible to compute the avoidability index of a given word $w$ (the least $k$ such that $w$ is $k$-avoidable) is open according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unavoidable_pattern) Wikipedia page, but I'm not sure whether this case of it is still open.

If it is still open, what is the current state of progress on the question?

Comment: The problem is $NP$-complete: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1007/s00224-022-10090-z, (seems to be a recent result), so in particular, it is in $NP$ and has an exponential-time algorithm.

Comment: @caduk This paper appears to concern the decision problem of whether a word is unavoidable (that is, $n$-unavoidable for every $n$), not $2$-avoidable (or $n$-avoidable for any fixed $n$).

Comment: Not my domain, so I hope I don't say some nonsense. Lemma 2.3 provides an explicit upper lower bound on words on an alphabet $r$ that avoids all patterns of size $n$. This bound, though enormous, is computable, so $k$-avoidability should be decidable (though not in practice). Such a bound (but not as precise), seems to exist since the work of Zimin, so it predates the reference given by wikipedia on the open problem (but to be fair, I don't see in the Lothaire's reference a mention of this open problem, I might have missed something...)